# uitableviewCell long press didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tap, long-press

As the question states,I put several UITableView on ScrollView ,so I can swipe and see different UITableView with different content . But when I tap the UITableViewCell , it can't response

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method .  I already set the delegate and dataSource.
It is very weired that when I long press the UITableViewCell ,it response this method.

very confused me.

Comment: does this issue arises when multiple tables are placed in scrollview??? or the issue persists even when there exists single table?? This could be a scrollview content size issue..not sure

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason after repeat checking the codes. It is because I added one UITapgesture on the ScrollView. It become normal after I delete it .